# Checkbox as alternative to captcha?

Tags: captcha, bots

Does a checbox provide an alternative to using captcha on website? I am thinking i i need to use captcha for user signup. Instead if i put a checkbox for the terms like "By clicking here I agree...." can that solve the bots issues or is captcha required in addition to the checkbox?

Comment: @you may consider offering a simple calculation to distinguish human from computer, such like, "what is the answer for 1+2?", where 1 and 2 are two randomly generated numbers.

Comment: @Michael: It would take five minutes to write a program that bypasses that technique. To make it intractable, you would have to generate thousands of different questions that are worded in subtly different ways such that only humans could interpret them.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos : I totoally agree.

Comment: I would be thrilled to be developing a web site that some hacker cared enough about that they wrote code to bypass my bot check. That is to say, if you find yourself being defeated by non-standard code that someone wrote just for you, then probably you have enough street cred that you should just use a real captcha.

Comment: Ah, but do spambots really care about individual web sites? No. They care about total volume. There are far more helpless, weak victims on the 'net whose pages they can sodomize.

Comment: @Christian Mann, exactly. The club doesn't really protect your car very well, it just makes it less interesting than the car next to it without one.

Answer (score 6):

One thing you can do with a checkbox is to make a [honeypot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing)). To do so, you would make a checkbox and hide it with CSS (because bots, as a rule, don't care about CSS). If the box is checked, then it's probably a bot.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but you can bet the guys behind the bots will soon find a way around it, for now a captcha is the best way.

Comment: Oh, certainly a CAPTCHA is the best way. But if for some reason he doesn't want to load an image, or any other drawback to CAPTCHA, this is an option.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to keep bots from signing up, they will be able to check the checkbox pretty easy.  the point of the captcha is that it takes human intelligence.

Answer (score 1):

No, bots can check boxes, use a service such as http://www.google.com/recaptcha to easily make a bot-proof form.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all, a checkbox is just like any other input, which bots manipulate.

As recommended above recaptcha is good. I also like [Akismet](http://akismet.com/), which handles this completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox Captcha generated with client-side Javascript can be an interesting option.

Check out that article published by UX Movement: "Captchas vs. Spambots: Why the Checkbox Captcha Wins" http://uxmovement.com/forms/captchas-vs-spambots-why-the-checkbox-captcha-wins).

Answer (score 0):

This technique can work, but it is not too difficult to beat, given time and an interest in your specific site.

Using CSS and Javascript (which isn't completely accessible) to create the checkbox will defeat the more simplistic spambots.
Also using a randomized name (which is verified server-side) for the checkbox POST/GET variable, and perhaps an image for the label (which creates more accessibility problems) will help make this more difficult.

In the end this should work fine, until someone takes the time to target your site or system specifically.

**Edit** The article linked to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7358784/289203) has  good information.