# Why is my controller being called twice from an email link

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Been struggling with this for hours.

This is a asp.net core 3.0 app.

It emails an activation link. 
I then pick up that email in my inbox and click on it.
This link is:

```
https://apc01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myserver.com%2FAccount%2FActivate%3Fpin%3DwDiC3S&data=02%7C01%7C%7C8311079d8b314d288f7a08d77e73c924%7C84df9e7fe9f640afb435aaaaaaaaaaaa%7C1%7C0%7C637116908072496731&sdata=y80XhRTBI%2FOJq6UrN8Yw%2B3nWDjrb96IprWR2IKIouVU%3D&reserved=0
```

It then emails me a confirmation message 9#by calling that view). But it does this twice. 
What is weird is that if I copy and past this url from 1 browser to another I just receive the expected 1 confirmation email.

The only difference I can see is that the safelink stuff add si removed from copying and pasting that link. ie:

```
https://www.myserver.com/Account/Activate?pin=wDiC3S
```

I do not know how to debug this?

Comment: Inspect the `Request` object under the debugger, it might give you some hints.

Comment: @mxmissile in my browser? As nothing there. I have also attached the process and nothing there either.  I just see my controller-view being called twice.  The page-view it is calling has nothing in it..

Comment: No, visual studio's debugger.

Comment: yes, done all that. First obvious thing to do. But thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just come across this situation. It has taken me a few days to track down. I have a link within an outlook message and I wrote code to make sure it was not called twice. This code was activated the first time I called it. Eventually I realised that the email client must be calling it twice. I'm going to have to write a work around.

I'm glad I found it. It was driving me mad!

I would consider this to be an outlook bug.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with outlook. The code you wrote to prevent double call inside is inside the e-mail code or in the server code?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with outlook. The code you wrote to prevent double call inside is inside the e-mail code or in the server code?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem a while back that seemed to be tied to the email client pre-fetching and visiting the link.  You may want to try a different email provider and client as part of your debugging efforts.

Here is a related question on the topic - 
[How to stop e-mail clients from visiting links in e-mail automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443947/how-to-stop-e-mail-clients-from-visiting-links-in-e-mail-automatically)

Comment: Ah! very interesting. I am rebooting my server and client desktop after windows updating to make sure and to clear cache. Before I try using a different client etc I will try using a button. I will try all this tomorrow morning and report back Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue couple of days already. With trial and error i just found out the solution with my own testing, you just need to set-up the **SMTP** configuration with your outlook account.

Using PHPMailer

I have this configuration before

```
$trans = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance()
->setHost("xxxxxxxxxxx.mail.protection.outlook.com")
->setPort(25);
```

I changed to

```
$trans = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.office365.com', 587, 'tls')
->setUsername('xxxxx@xxxxxxx')
->setPassword('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

Now, it's working properly. I think ATP aka SafeLink Protection Feature will work only if the email address(sender) is not verified within your organization.