When sending a mail using SES, the links inside the mails are called automatically , instead they are only clicked by the reciever
I'm using AWS SES to send HTML emails that contain two hyperlinks. The intended behavior is for these links to be clicked manually by the email recipients. However, I'm encountering an issue where the links are being automatically triggered (likely by email clients or security tools that prefetch or scan URLs for safety). This is causing unintended actions on my server.
How can I prevent these links from being automatically accessed and ensure they are only activated when the recipient manually clicks them? I'm looking for a solution that can be implemented either within the email content, through AWS SES configurations, or via server-side handling.
I used boto3 ses service to call the API

There's not really a great way to stop this. Most effective thing for you to do would be make it so your server only performs an action after a 'post' from the client, rather than a 'get' -- so have the link go to a form that maybe just contains a single button for the user to then fire it from.

a couple of technical solutions are suggested here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443947/how-to-stop-e-mail-clients-from-visiting-links-in-e-mail-automatically -- but it's basically whack-a-mole.

Thanks  TZHX, for your quick response. We wanted to eliminate the  User interactions(login) to our application but it seems there is no other way, we will continue with the approval page inside our app itself.

How I resolved is using the Get and Post request, I had put Get links in the mail and it renders the html form. the form has post request confirming the action. This way I prevented the links from becoming invalid.
